# Is possible Launching testing framework on client side to test other app in local network

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I explain.

I need to create a standalone "MainWebApp" that allows the members of my organization to test a "third WebAapp".

`A-WebApp` (Standalone - runs testing framework) -> `Client` (Visits `A-WebApp` and exeute test to `B-Webapp`) ->  `B-Webapp` (Client connects to this app and execute test that are stablished in `A-WebApp`)

Is it possible to do this with some framework that I can recommend that is easy and fast to use?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Selenium GRID`.

Use `selenium server standalone.jar` file from the Official site. Run the `jar` file on machine `B-webapp`, set up grid and nodes in that machine (tutorials are available online for free).

Once you have a `Selenium GRID` up and running on `B-webapp` you just need to open `A-WebApp` and create `RemoteWebDriver`.

`RemoteWebDriver` is an instance of `WebDriver` just like `Firefox` or `Chrome` driver.

`RemoteWebDriver` execute tests against `Selenium GRID`

How to use `RemoteWebDriver:`

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
String url = "SELENIUM GRID URL";
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(url), capability);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Can I mount selenium RemoteWebdrier in `B-webApp` through a Java application such as JSF or Servlet to visit it from `Client` and in turn the `client` can go to a `B-WebApp` and run the tests?

Know of the existence of an example similar to this.

Comment: @CAlonsoCOrtega I don't know any examples. I don't think anyone does that. Can you be more specific on what are you trying to do? I have a hard time understanding what is the concept you are trying to achieve

Comment: I hope to be clearer.
`A-Webapp` (Main Server)
Could it be inside a Java application container such as `JSF` or `Java-Servlet`?
Allows the `client`(user) to perform test flow (test flow 1, 2 or 3)
By means of a button it executes the test flow selected in the `client` (client side) with `selenium framework`.

`B-Webapp` (App to be tested)
Run a third standalone webapp that needs to be tested by some `clients` (users)

Comment: `Client`(user)
It connects to `A-Webapp` and captures some test parameters such as:
Select a test flow 1, 2 or 3
Enter an .xlsx file for test flow 1.
Enter 100 names for test flow 2.
Enter 10 numbers for the test flow 3.
Run the test flows with the `selenium framework`.

I am very sorry for the inconvenience and I greatly appreciate your attention.

I'm stuck with this :(

Comment: Selenium is just an API so you can wrap it around using Java and yes, you can perform tests like this. You can probably do this in many ways.

Pass parameters from GUI to separate module which runs Selenium WebDriver tests against the desired web application.

Unfortunately, You have to do this on your own. You will not find many if any, examples. The plus side is - it's doable.